# Using Speechlib from SAPI (Microsoft text to speech API) as an Unity AudioSource

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, sapi

I'm building an app which has a chatbot and uses SAPI for text to speech along with SALSA asset for LypSync. What i'm trying to accomplish is to create a live AudioSource that feeds directly from TTS audio output. I have successfully accomplished this thru saving into wav files for each sentence and then loading the wav files in runtime to the GameObject that has the LypSync etc. This works, but the continuous loading of wav files makes the app be slow, freezes each time it does that and even crashes.

I know it's possible to make a live AudioSource from a microphone on the computer. So what I want to do is something like that.

I tried what from my naive level of programmer would be the logic way. Simply connect the udioOutput stream from the TTS as a AudiSource audio clip, like this:

```
TTSvoice.AudioOutputStream = AudioSource.clip;
```

and get this error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.AudioClip' to  SpeechLib.ISpeechBaseStream'`SpeechLib.ISpeechBaseStream'

I know in Python you can connect audio objects from different libraries thru numpy converting audio to a standard raw array data. But I'm also kinda new to C# and Unity.

here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 using SpeechLib;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.IO;
 using System;
 using System.Diagnostics;

 public class controller : MonoBehaviour {


 private SpVoice voice;
 public AudioSource soundvoice;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

     voice = new SpVoice();

     GameObject character = GameObject.Find("character");
     soundvoice = character.GetComponent(typeof(AudioSource)) as AudioSource;

     voice.AudioOutputStream = soundvoice.clip;

     StartCoroutine(talksome());
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {



 }

 IEnumerator talksome() {
     while (true)
     {
         counter++;
         string sentence = "counting " + counter;
         voice.Speak(sentence);
         print(sentence);

         voice.WaitUntilDone(1);
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: First: You can delete Update function-> even though is empty Unity will call it every frame. Secondly I am not an expert on the text to speech field, however your error is that you about of mismatched data types. You are casting the source-destination incorrectly.

Comment: I know where is my error as I described on my question already.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with Unity, but it looks like what you need to do is to supply a custom `PCMReaderCallback` delegate to the AudioClip that would adapt the data from the `AudioOutputStream` (in particular, it needs to normalize the data from 16-bit ints to floats).